# How does one stub promise with sinon?

Tags: javascript, jasmine, sinon

I have a data service with following function

```
function getInsureds(searchCriteria) {

    var deferred = $q.defer();

    insuredsSearch.get(searchCriteria,
        function (insureds) {
            deferred.resolve(insureds);
        },
        function (response) {
            deferred.reject(response);
        });

    return deferred.promise;
}
```

I want to test following function:

```
function search ()
{
  dataService
      .getInsureds(vm.searchCriteria)
      .then(function (response) {
           vm.searchCompleted = true;

            if (response.insureds.length > 100) {
              vm.searchResults = response.insureds.slice(0, 99);
            } else {
                vm.searchResults = response.insureds;
           }
       });
}
```

How would I stub the promise so that when I call getInsureds it would resolve the promise and return me the results immediately. I started like this (jasmine test), but I am stuck, as I don't know how to resolve the promise and pass in arguments needed.

```
it("search returns over 100 results searchResults should contain only 100 records ", function () {

    var results103 = new Array();

    for (var i = 0; i < 103; i++) {
        results103.push(i);
    }

    var fakeSearchForm = { $valid: true };
    var isSearchValidStub = sinon.stub(sut, "isSearchCriteriaValid").returns(true);

    var deferred = $q.defer();
    var promise = deferred.promise;
    var dsStub = sinon.stub(inSearchDataSvc, "getInsureds").returns(promise);

    var resolveStub = sinon.stub(deferred, "resolve");

    //how do i call resolve  and pass in results103

    sut.performSearch(fakeSearchForm);

    sinon.assert.calledOnce(isSearchValidStub);
    sinon.assert.calledOnce(dsStub);

    sinon.assert.called(resolveStub);

    expect(sut.searchResults.length).toBe(100);

});
```

Answer (score 26, accepted):

You just have to resolve the promise before you call the search function. This way your stub will return a resolved promise and `then` will be called immediately. So instead of

```
var resolveStub = sinon.stub(deferred, "resolve");
```

you will resolve the deferred with your fake response data

```
deferred.resolve({insureds: results103})
```

Comment: This doesn't agree with the promises we're using nowadays. [Promises/A+ say](https://promisesaplus.com/) "onFulfilled or onRejected must not be called until the execution context stack contains only platform code".

Comment: Actually, this is how I did it: `var resolveStub = sinon.stub(deferred, "resolve").returns({then:function(){}});`

Answer (score 103):

At current sinon version v2.3.1, you can use `stub.resolves(value)` and `stub.rejects(value)` function

For example, you can stub myClass.myFunction with following code

```
sinon.stub(myClass, 'myFunction').resolves('the value you want to return');
```

or

```
sinon.stub(myClass, 'myFunction').rejects('the error information you want to return');
```

Comment: This is elegant! Thanks!

Comment: Hi,   how do I get the returned value ?

Answer (score 12):

Also you can do something like this:

```
import sinon from 'sinon';

const sandbox = sinon.sandbox.create();

const promiseResolved = () => sandbox.stub().returns(Promise.resolve('resolved'));
const promiseRejected = () => sandbox.stub().returns(Promise.reject('rejected'));

const x = (promise) => {
  return promise()
    .then((result) => console.log('result', result))
    .catch((error) => console.log('error', error))
}

x(promiseResolved); // resolved
x(promiseRejected); // rejected
```

Answer (score 8):

I had a similar situation and the accepted answer and comments were not working, but along with [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28407031/typeerror-cannot-read-property-then-of-undefined-in-testing-angularjs-control) they helped me solve this in the following way. I hope it is helpful for somebody.

```
var Promise = require('bluebird');

var deferred = Promise.defer();
stub = sinon.stub(deferred, 'resolve').returns(deferred.promise);

deferred.resolve({data: data});
// or
deferred.reject(new Error('fake error'));
```

Answer (score 1):

There's one more alternative I found. Much pain free than other methods.

You can use this npm package: [sinon-stub-promise](https://github.com/substantial/sinon-stub-promise).

It abstracts much of the details, so that you don't have to invent the wheel again. Helped my write my tests after struggling to simulate a promise for long.

Hope it helps!