# AngularJS unit-testing basics: testing for a $q deferred object's resolution and rejection in a service

Tags: angularjs, unit-testing, testing, jasmine, promise

I'm learning angularJS unit-testing and I'm struggling unit testing a basic "login" function on an "AuthenticationService" service.

The service method uses `$q.defer()` to set up a promise and then rejects or resolves it based on input.

How do I spy on or otherwise test that promise?

What is wrong with the below? The test fails - error is "undefined" rather than 'AuthenticationService.login - missing argument'

Hopefully it is obvious what I am trying to do, I can't really put it into words.

**The Service**

```
angular.module('moduleName').factory('AuthenticationService', function($q, $http) {
    var serviceObject = {
        login = function(credential, password) {
            var d = $q.defer();

              // check if any fields are missing
              if (!credential && !password || credential === '' || password === '') {
                d.reject('AuthenticationService.login - missing argument');
              } else {
                var sacho = {message: "I'm so confused"};
                d.resolve(sacho);
                }

               return d.promise;
            }
        }
    };

    return serviceObject;
});
```

**The Test**

```
describe('AuthenticationService', function()
{
  var scope, AuthenticationService, $httpBackend;

  beforeEach(inject(function($rootScope, _AuthenticationService_, _$httpBackend_) {
    scope = $rootScope.$new();
    AuthenticationService = _AuthenticationService_;
    MemberLookup = _MemberLookup_;
    $httpBackend = _$httpBackend_;
  }));

  describe('Logging In', function() {
    it('promise should be rejected if any fields are empty', function() {
      AuthenticationService.login('','').catch(function(error){
        expect(error).toEqual('AuthenticationService.login - missing argument');
      });
    });
  });
});
```

**EDIT:** `AuthenticationService.login` returns a promise.

The promise should be rejected if either of the credentials to the method are blank or missing.

In the test code (below) I have tried to write a test to see if the promise is rejected. The test inputs blank strings as arguments to the `AuthenticationService.login` method. The expected behaviour is the promise being rejected with the string `'AuthenticationService.login - missing argument'`. However, running the test fails - `Authentication.Service.login('','').catch`'s callback does not work as expected.

I have also tried using `.then(null, callback)`.

How do I spy on the promise returned by `AuthenticationService.login` when given specific 
parameters?

Comment: i'm not sure what is the question here, can you please explain which code are you trying to test?

Comment: If there is nothing asynchronous there, you should not be using a promise in the first place.

Comment: Liad Livnat: `AuthenticationService.login` returns a promise. 

The promise should be rejected if either of the credentials to the method are blank or missing. 

I have tried to write a test to see if the promise is rejected. The test inputs blank strings as arguments to the `login` method. The expected behaviour is the promise being rejected with a string. However, the test fails - `login('','').catch`'s callback does not work as expected.

I have also tried using `.then(null, callback)`.

How do I spy on the promise returned by `AuthenticationService.login` when given specific 
parameters?

Comment: @BenjaminGruenbaum - Good point, there is some asynchronous work if the `(!credential && !password || credential === '' || password === '')` condition is not satisfied.  I omitted it for the purposes of the SO question.

Comment: To test promises I use Sinon (mocking library), in this test how mock a promise: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20555234/how-does-one-stub-promise-with-sinon

Answer (score 3):

```
it('promise should be rejected if any fields are empty', function(done) {
  AuthenticationService.login('','').catch(function(error){
    expect(error).toEqual('AuthenticationService.login - missing argument');
    done()
  });
  scope.$digest()
});
```

**done** - to explain you test framework when it's ready (in case of async operations)

**scope.$digest()** - to resolve all the promises

Comment: I'm now getting `TypeError: 'undefined' is not a function (evaluating '$rootScope.digest())` but this makes a lot more sense!

Comment: I'm sorry, it should be "$" sign there before digest

Comment: it works without done()! thank you!!!! - but with done() I get an error `TypeError: 'undefined' is not a function (evaluating 'done()')`

Comment: Note that the done() method was only added in version 2 of Jasmine. If you're using the Karma test-runner it still installs version 1.3 or something which is probably why done() isn't working for you. You can manually install version 2 of Jasmine and it will work fine with Karma.