# Mock promises in angularjs

Tags: javascript, angularjs, unit-testing, promise, angular-promise

I tried to mocking angular promises but I got some errors like undefined is not a function evaluating 'spyOn' fileUploadService

My controller code is

```
$scope.getUserFiles = function() {
    fileUploadService.retrieveUserFileNames('')
    .then(function(data) {
        $scope.userFiles =  data;
    });
};
```

service code, I call this method from my controller

```
this.retrieveUserFileNames= function(userId) {
    var deferred = $q.defer();
    $http({
        method : "GET",
        url : "/retrieveExcelSheetNames",
        params : {
            "userId" : userId
        }
    }).success(function(data) {
        deferred.resolve(data);
    }).error(function(data, status) {
        deferred.reject(data);
    });
    return deferred.promise;
};
```

test controller code

```
beforeEach(function() {
    inject(function(_fileUploadService_ , _$q_) {
        spyOn(scope, '$on');
        var deferred = _$q_.defer();
        fileUploadService = _fileUploadService_;
        deferred.resolve('resolveData');
        spyOn(fileUploadService, 'retrieveUserFileNames').andReturn(deferred.promise);
    });
});

it('is now a lot easier', function() {
   scope.getUserFiles();
   rootScope.$apply();
   expect(scope.userFiles).toBe('resolveData');
});
```

Thanks

Comment: I use Sinon to mock promises, it simplifies the mocking creation process for me, take a look at: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20555234/how-does-one-stub-promise-with-sinon

Comment: Why are you doing $q.defer? You an simply `return $http(...`

Comment: @BenjaminGruenbaum in my services I have asynchronous $http call thats why I'm used $q

Comment: Right, all I said is that you don't need to use `$q.defer` in your code. Using $q and $http is perfectly fine :)

Comment: I have some issues with $http due to that asynchronous calls, so I preferred $q.defer..

Answer (score 2):

As you're asynchronously set `$scope.userFiles` in your controller so you need to wait for the `$apply` from `$http` that resolved your promise.

Assuming you're using Jasmine you could use the asynchronous spec notation and register a `$watch` function to test your controller (Didn't test the code so you might need to tune it and it also depends on other modifications of the scope variable).

```
it('is now a lot easier', function(done) {
  scope.$watch('userFiles', function() {
     expect(scope.userFiles).toBe('resolveData');
     // Call done function to tell Jasmine that the spec has completed
     done();
  });

  scope.getUserFiles();
});
```

However, I think you should rather test your service and you can use [$httpBackend from ngMock](https://code.angularjs.org/1.2.20/docs/api/ngMock/service/$httpBackend) which is overriding $http and enables you to test much more in-depth. There you can test / spy the calls to the mock backend and also use Jasmines `done()` function to wait for the promise.

Here is a simple exmaple:

```
angular.module('mainApp', [])
  // Simple factory that uses $http for later use of $httpBackend mocking structure
  .factory('userManager', function($http, $q) {
     return $http.get('/api/users');
  });
```

And the specs:

```
describe('Simple factory that uses $http for later use of $httpBackend mocking structure', function() {
  // We need to use the module mainApp for all our tests
  beforeEach(module('mainApp'));

  // We use $httpBackend from ngMock module to mock our webservice call ($http will be overriden)
  // Also we need to inject inside of spec function as we need to use the async spec form with
  // a done function and this is not available using the inject to proxy the spec function
  it('should return desired user list', function(done) {

    inject(function($httpBackend, userManager) {

      $httpBackend.when('GET', '/api/users').respond({
        userList: [
          {user: 'User A'},
          {user: 'User B'},
          {user: 'User C'},
          {user: 'User D'},
        ]
      });
      $httpBackend.expectGET('/api/users');

      // userManager is returning a promise so we need to check asynchronously
      userManager.getUserList().then(function(result) {
        expect(result.data.userList).toContain(
          {user: 'User A'}, 
          {user: 'User B'}, 
          {user: 'User C'}, 
          {user: 'User D'}
        );

        // This call to the Jasmine done function is very important for asynchronous
        // unit tests as Jasmine is determining if the test is done by this call
        done();
      });

      $httpBackend.flush();

      $httpBackend.verifyNoOutstandingExpectation();
      $httpBackend.verifyNoOutstandingRequest();
    });
  });
});
```

Comment: @BenjaminGruenbaum I'm well aware what the deferred anti pattern is but if you look closer I'm just creating a layer of encapsulation because I don't want the $http promise to leave the service but create my own promise that resolves directly to a specific array in my result. **This absolutely makes sense specially because the $http promises are enriched with a cancel function and I don't want to give this control outside my service**. Please reconsider your devote.

Comment: If you fix your example with userListDefer I'll gladly revert my downvote.

Comment: @BenjaminGruenbaum check my comment update in bold. If you still think I don't have a valid reason to wrap the promise then let me know with a valid explanation.

Comment: I still think you don't have a valid reason to wrap the promise. Just because you're returning a subtype of promise doesn't mean it's not a promise. If what bothers you is the fact you're returning a subtype (it really shouldn't) you can return `$q.when($http(...` which wouldn't be nearly as bad (because it can't leak or suppress errors) but would still be redundant imo.

Comment: In order to simplify the example and fix the anti-pattern I'm okay to change the example. Still, if you consider that a caller of getUserList would be able to cancel the request by calling .cancel() on the promise would be a design issue for me so I'd prefer to wrap it.