# Unit testing angularjs with mocha/chai should.have.been.called not working

Tags: angularjs, mocha.js, sinon, chai

The following test passes whether my expect statement is

```
expect(propertyFactory.readProperty).should.have.been.called;
```

or

```
expect(propertyFactory.readProperty).should.have.not.been.called;
```

I've tried this with or without the sinon stub.

```
describe('pf.propertyModule', function () {

  var controller;
  var propertyFactory;

  beforeEach(module('pf.core'));
  beforeEach(module('pf.propertyModule'));

  beforeEach(inject(function(_propertyFactory_) {
    propertyFactory = _propertyFactory_;
    /*
    sinon.stub(propertyFactory, 'readProperty', function() {
      return {
        data: {
          property: 'xyz'
        }
      }
    });*/
  }));

  describe('readPropertyCtrl', function () {
    it('should have a passing first test', function () {
      expect(propertyFactory.readProperty).should.have.been.called;
    });
  });
});
```

UPDATE: Ok, so I got past the initial "non-error" by ensuring "sinon-chai" was installed, but now I'm getting the output: thrown: [Function] } is not a spy or a call to a spy!

UPDATE: Ok, so I got the previous error working by calling sinon.spy(). However, now I'm wondering how one would go about mocking a method that is expected to return a promise.  I'm getting the error " TypeError: 'undefined' is not an object (evaluating 'propertyFactory.readProperty({id: $stateParams.id}).then')
"

Updated code:

```
describe('pf.propertyModule', function () {

  var ctrl;
  var scope;
  var propertyFactory;

  beforeEach(module('pf.core'));
  beforeEach(module('pf.propertyModule'));

  beforeEach(inject(function($rootScope, $controller) {
    scope = $rootScope.$new();
    propertyFactory = {
      readProperty: sinon.spy()
    };
    ctrl = $controller('readPropertyCtrl as vm', {
      $scope: scope,
      propertyFactory: propertyFactory
    });
  }));

  describe('readPropertyCtrl', function () {
    it('should have a passing first test', function () {
      expect(scope.vm).to.be.defined;
      expect(propertyFactory.readProperty).should.have.been.called;
    });
  });
});
```

Code to test:

```
propertyFactory.readProperty({id: $stateParams.id}).then(getPropertySuccess);
function getPropertySuccess(response) {
  vm.loadedProperty = response.data.property;
}
```

Updated Code:

```
describe('pf.propertyModule', function () {

  var ctrl;
  var scope;
  var propertyFactory;

  beforeEach(module('pf.core'));
  beforeEach(module('pf.propertyModule'));

  beforeEach(inject(function($rootScope, $controller, $q, _propertyFactory_) {

    scope = $rootScope.$new();
    propertyFactory = _propertyFactory_;
    var deferred = $q.defer();
    var promise = deferred.promise;
    sinon.stub(propertyFactory, "readProperty").returns(promise);
    deferred.resolve({property: 'xyz'});

    ctrl = $controller('readPropertyCtrl as vm', {
      $scope: scope,
      propertyFactory: propertyFactory
    });
  }));

  describe('readPropertyCtrl', function () {
    it('should have a passing first test', function () {
      expect(scope.vm).to.be.defined;
      expect(propertyFactory.readProperty).should.have.been.called;
    });
  });
});
```

This attempt is returning thrown: [Function] } is not a spy or a call to a spy!

Comment: I'm not sure what you are trying to do but you should only be doing assertions such as .should.have.benn.called on stubs/spys

Comment: @WayneEllery Refer to the updated code.

Comment: It's best to post the part of code you are testing

Comment: Okay, I just posted the piece of code being tested.

Comment: Why are you injecting in propertyFactory when it should be mocked as you are unit testing the controller?

Comment: Because I was trying anything and everything to get this to work.

Comment: If you notice, that isn't actually being used.

Comment: Updated the code to exactly how it is now.

Comment: Have you tried using $q to return a promise?

Comment: I have not.  I'm not entirely sure how I would go about doing that.

Comment: Take a look at this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20555234/how-does-one-stub-promise-with-sinon

Comment: Tried the approach in that post (updated code posted above), but it's not working.

Comment: Is it possible to setup a Plunkr/jsfiddle?